How to Capture a Specific View as a Bitmap in Android?
I'm building an Android app in Kotlin, and I want to capture a particular View (like a TextView or ImageView) as a Bitmap. I’ve read that DrawingCache can help with this, but I’m unsure if it’s the best approach. I need the bitmap to save or share as an image later.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Enabled drawingCache for the view.
Used Canvas to draw the view into a Bitmap.

I want to capture the view as a Bitmap so I can later save it as an image or share it.

DrawingCache is an option, it’s outdated, and the preferred method now is to use a Bitmap and Canvas to capture the view's contents.
Kotlin Code
fun captureViewAsBitmap(view: View): Bitmap {
    // Create a bitmap with the same width and height as the view
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    
    // Draw the view onto the canvas, which will render it to the bitmap
    view.draw(canvas)
    
    return bitmap
}

Java Code
public Bitmap captureViewAsBitmap(View view) {
    // Create a bitmap with the same width and height as the view
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    // Draw the view onto the canvas, which will render it to the bitmap
    view.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}

